# exception handling - AttributeErrror: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'sleep'

Tags: python, exception

I'm running a script to collect all the lifetime tweets of a list of users. As a result, I've had to add an exception handling bit for when my credentials time out. The error I'm currently receiving is:

> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "PROJECT_july.py", line 108,
>   in 
>       time.sleep(60 * 5) AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'sleep'

The script I've used to handle the error is:

```
except tweepy.TweepError:
    time.sleep(60 * 5)
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
    auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET)
    api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
    print("tweep error avoided: tweepy.TweepError XXX2")
```

Please note - I'm just using 'import time' (deleted 'import datetime' the first time I received this error!).

Any advice is massively appreciated!

Thank you,

Comment: You have probably used `time` as a variable name for a datetime object.

Comment: you probably have a `time = datetime` somewhere else in your code, assigning a `datetime` object to the variable `time`

Comment: @DavidG you beat me with 15 seconds

Comment: yep - you're right - thank you. I had:   time = status.created_at. Going to back all of this stuff out and re-run. Thank you :)